# Avoid python interpreting % as a placeholder in like mysql clause

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, formatting

I'm trying to create a DataFrame through a sql query with pandas `read_sql_query` method. The query has a `where` clause that includes a `like` operation but it also includes a `=` operation that depends on a variable. The issue is that python is interpreting the `%` in the `like` operation as a place holder, just like in the `= variable` operation which is something I DO want.

Here's an example of it:

```
sql_string = """ SELECT a,b from table WHERE a = %(variable)s 
    AND b like '%fixed_chars%' """
params = {'variable':'AA'}
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_string, params=params, con=connection)
```

The error that I get is `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string` since it interprets the `%` you usually use as wildcard in mysql as the place holder in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you'll have to use **two** `%` for those not being formatting placeholders:

```
sql_string = "SELECT a,b from table WHERE a = %(variable)s AND \
    b like '%%fixed_chars%%'"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: just a question, why the `!` at the beginning of the statement?

Comment: Oops, typo... Thanks!