# MariaDB not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, datetime, mariadb

```
for i, row in tables.iterrows():
    year = row['Tables_in_log_20220114_msn'][4:8]
    month = row['Tables_in_log_20220114_msn'][8:10]
    date = row['Tables_in_log_20220114_msn'][10:12]
    result = year + '-' + month + '-' + date

    res = pd.read_sql(
    f'''SELECT id, user_id, ipaddress, status, error, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('{result}', ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as 'datetime' FROM {row['Tables_in_log_20220114_msn']} LIMIT 5;''',
    con=engine)
    break
```

The error it returns:

```
ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) not enough arguments for format string
[SQL: SELECT id, user_id, ipaddress, status, error, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018-01-01', ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as 'datetime' FROM log_20180101 LIMIT 5;]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

---

I can't show extra code.
But what is the issue here why does it do this and how do i fix it?

Comment: I do not see any error related to MySQL, if time is a column in this format `12:00:00` the query seems fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca5a072fa748f94e038a94c9b2f7ffb8 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563660/avoid-python-interpreting-as-a-placeholder-in-like-mysql-clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid python interpreting % as a placeholder in like mysql clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563660/avoid-python-interpreting-as-a-placeholder-in-like-mysql-clause)

Comment: upgrade mysqlclient - recent version is 2.1.1.

Comment: The answers have not fixed my problem. I still get the same error

Comment: Looks as if the `time` column contains more than just hour:minute:second. What does `SELECT time, CONCAT('2018-01-01', ' ', time) FROM log_20180101 LIMIT 5;
` return?